# Finite looping a video file in quicktime or MP4 container and keeping file size down to single loop original size?

Tags: vlc-media-player, quicktime

I'm trying to find a way to create a very long but finite (limit of 100x) looping movie from a 2 mintue clip, and keep the file size down to only the original single loop.

(So am hoping a container format like Quicktime that contains the actual movie can be told to access that one actual movie 100x only).

Perhaps it can be done in Quicktime Pro(?) by copying and pasting my movie inside quicktime pro 100x, and then exporting using 'Passthough'? i.e., will I end up with a file size nearly as small as my original single loop, or will I end up with a file size 100x bigger?

Or can I do it with VLC or FFMPG, or another?

The loop is HD and needs to be uploaded to a certain destination in high quality across the internet.  It won't work at all to have a file size 100x bigger than a single loop.
And it must play looping correctly 100x at the destination without my having any influence or control over the automated player at the recipient's end.

Any suggestions towards achieving this are most welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, chances are you won't be able to do what you're asking.  The exception would be, as you said, if you are able to specify repetition within the player or the format itself, which sounds unlikely.  If you want to actually create a new, full video of all 100 repetitions with the original quality, then the result will have a filesize ~100x larger than the original.

Comment: Actually, after reading this page, I believe it is technically possible to do in Quicktime: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/RM/Fundamentals/QTOverview/QTOverview_AIntro/Introduction.html


However, it might require a novel quicktime editing application. Unless anyone can advise of such an application already in existence?
Or again, perhaps Quicktime Pro can do it. (I don't yet own it to try it).

Comment: I did a quick Google, and it looks like Quicktime Pro does have a "Loop" option, though it looked like it means indefinitely.  I think what you may want is a script that constantly replays the video until a loop terminates.  I think you might be able to do this using AppleScript, it might be worth taking a look.

Comment: It sounds like the sort of job that AviSynth would handle quite nicely. Essentially you have a text file which your player handles as a video file. You can specify finite loops of a particular video file inside the AviSynth file.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps it can be done in Quicktime Pro(?) by copying and pasting my movie inside quicktime pro 100x

That's exactly how it works in QuickTime Pro:

- Make a copy of your QuickTime mov file
- Select All <kbd>⌘A</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>
- Copy <kbd>⌘C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
- Playhead to end <kbd>⌥Right</kbd> / <kbd>Alt+Right</kbd>
- Paste <kbd>⌘V</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>
- Save <kbd>⌘S</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>

You're file will barely be bigger.

You still wonder why MPEG chose to make mp4 a derivative of mov? ;-)